# Problem with footer positioning on first TOC page (originated on fancyhdr header)

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

the footer on my first TOC page is not showing in the right position. My code (very simplified, I made a copy of the class and document used, made cuts until I found out the problem and generated this code snipet) is below:

```
\documentclass[10.5pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[a4paper,vmargin={3cm,3.2cm},hmargin={3cm,3cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} 

\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

%if I comment the line below it works
\fancyhead[C]{\includegraphics[height=38pt]{sampleimage.png}}

\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\cfoot{\includegraphics[height=28pt]{anyimage.png}}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\part{First Part}
\cleardoublepage
\chapter{firstchapter}

\end{document}
```

If I comment the mentioned line it works, but the header won't show as I wish. Anyone know why this is happening? How can I fix it (maintaining the header the way I want)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get a warning of the `fancyhdr` package? For example, `Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small` would refer to that. In that case adjust it using `\setlength{\headheight}{...}` then or your layout might be harmed - your image is bigger than the default head height.

Comment: @Stefan The problem is indeed the size of the image. I did set up the headheight and it worked! Please add this as answer so I can accept your answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the content of the header is too big such that it doesn't match the value of `\headheight`, the layout can be damaged. In such cases the `fancyhdr` package would print out a warning:

```
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small
```

It can be repaired by adjusting that length by `\setlength{\headheight}{...}`.